# jQuery ajax sending multiple request on 1 click

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i don't know what happened to my code i am clicking on send button send email and its sending multiple duplicate emails.. Same jQuery and html code used in another page for delete files and working fine..
is i am doing some thing? wrong ?
[image]

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click','.sendwork',function(e){
    $('#spinner').show();
    var sendWork = $(this).data('id');

    var res         = sendWork.split("-");
    var comment_id  =  res[0];
    var status      =  res[1];
    var order_id    =  res[2];
    var td = $(this).closest("td").andSelf();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{!! URL::to('admin/sendwork/') !!}',
        cache: false,
        data:{
         '_token'   : '{{ csrf_token() }}',
         'comment_id':comment_id,
         'status':status,
         order_id:order_id,
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#spinner').hide();
            if (data == 'true') {
                // $('.email-resp').html('');
                td.html('Email Sent');
            }

        },
        error:function(data){
            $('#spinner').hide();
            td.html('<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Fail</p>');
        }
    });

 });
```

**html:**

```
<table class="table table-compact table-bordered">

    <tr>
        <th width="10"></th>
        <th width="30">Date</th>
        <th width="20">User</th>
        <th width="20">Status</th>
        <th width="450">Comment</th>
        <th width="100">Files</th>
    <th width="30">Action</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a class="del-comment" href="javascript:void(0)" data-token="XyjbZEsvbfTnurM0OnRP75k049Re0dPpLynRqUe6" id="217"><span style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a> </td>
        <td>01-Apr-15</td>
        <td width="30">hy</td>
        <td>Completed</td>
        <td width="42" align="left"><p>sdf</p></td>
        <td>
            <a href="/uploads/PE10_1427882386_0.png" target="_blank" alt="PE10_1427882386_0.png" title="PE10_1427882386_0.png"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></a>                  </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-small btn-success sendwork" data-id="217-Completed-LEH1000">Send</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: check with $(document).off('click').on('click',

Comment: How many elements have the class ".sendwork"?

Comment: where is the sendWork in html?

Comment: in this only one  button with sendwork class...

Comment: and sendWork storing data-id value

Comment: Check that you include this code in html only once. Try to add some console.log in your function, look how many time it printed. It is pretty hard to determine the problem from this part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on('click','.sendwork',function(e){
   // do some thing
});
```

Comment: How is this different from the jQuery mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).off('click').on('click', function(){
   //
});
```

will work

Comment: its working but when modal closed this will not going to open an other modal unless neee to refresh page..

Answer (score 3):

What helped in my case was to add `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` after calling the method:

```
$(document).on('click','.sendwork',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('click', '.sendwork',function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // this will help
});

$("#form").on('submit' ,function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // this help me in same issue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved i just changed the code:

form

```
$(document).on('click','.sendwork',function(e){
```

to

```
$('.sendwork').on('click',function(e){
```

Answer (score 1):

" I solved my issue adding $(‘#foo’).unbind(‘click’); in .done(function(data) event attached with $.ajax. Thank You!"

Solution here: http://eligeske.com/jquery/jquery-sending-multiple-ajax-requests-all-by-itself-kind-of/

Answer (score 0):

This code really works great for me.

```
$('.class').unbind().bind('eventName', method);
```

Answer (score 0):

use ***async:false*** to prevent multiple request

```
$(document).off('click').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: ,
        async:false,
        cache: false,
        data:{}
         ,
        success: function(data){

        },
        error:function(data){
        }
    });   

});
```